# Changing the color of a mask OpenCV 3

Tags: java, opencv

I want to change the color of my mask which is black to any different color.

Here is my mask

### [image]

and here is my original image

[image]

I know that if I use this function

```
src.copyTo(dst, mask);
```

it will allow me to use the mask properly and to have a result like this

[image]

However whenever I change the mask color to non black it doesn't make anything to `dst` Mat.

Is there a way to use a mask with non-black mask?

I don't want to use looping function because I know it'll cost me a lot of processing time.

Thanks

Comment: No there isn't the mask is meant to be in a binary format, (0 or 255) only, I wonder why would you need to change the color of mask ?

Comment: I need to change the color of the mask in order to remove the background and focus on the roi. The requirement is a custom background because the roi may sometimes have black pixels on it. I also wonder if there is a small function in which I can simply add two image together so that I don't have to use `copyTo` function to apply mask. I'm not used to using such operations though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't write Java, but you can try in C++:

```
// assume that origin image has 3 channels
cv::Scalar myColor(255,0,255);  

// create dst with background color of your choice
cv::Mat dst(src.size(),src.type(),myColor);

// now copy
src.copyTo(dst, mask);
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: How to do this in python?

Comment: @AnnaVopureta The steps are detailed in comments. You can try do so in Python. If you got stuck, feel free to open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a `bitwise_and` [operation](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Core.html#bitwise_and(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat)) performed on the mask and the original image. If I understand you correctly, there is no reason for changing the color of the mask.